# Is there a reason for uneven task distribution with celery + redis?

Tags: redis, celery

We used to have redis as the broker and rpc as the backend with our celery task queuing system. If we sent 50 tasks to 5 workers, each worker would reliably end up with 10 tasks.
Now that we switched to redis as the backend and broker, some workers get 20 tasks, some get 1, it seems to be completely arbitrary. No code has changed besides the backend + broker changing. Is there a reason for this?

The code I am running is very simple:

```
from time import sleep
def multiply(self, num_1, num_2):
    sleep(50)
    return num_1 * num_2
```

I am currently running it 1000 times across 30 nodes, and some workers are running 0 tasks and some are running 11. I really do not understand why some workers would have 0 tasks when there are still tasks in the queue waiting to be run.

Comment: Do you use `-O fair` ?

Comment: Tried it with and without, didn't see a noticeable difference